# How to Perform a SumProduct() in Pandas Using Two Separate Data Frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

**Objective:** Create an output with a comparable [SUMPRODUCT](https://magoosh.com/excel/sumproduct-formula-excel/) method within pandas

**Description:** There are two data frames that I need to make use of (df and df_2_copy). I am trying to add 1-mo CDs, 3-mo CDs, 6-mo CDs after multiplying each by their respective price in df (2000,3000,5000).

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['1-mo CDs', 1.0, 1,2000, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6'],
        ['3-mo CDs', 4.0 ,3 ,3000,'1 and 4'],
        ['6-mo CDs',9.0 ,6, 5000,'1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Scenario','Yield', 'Term','Price', 'Purchase CDs in months'])
df

data_2 = [['Init Cash', 400000, 325000,335000,355000,275000,225000,240000],
          ['Matur CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['Interest',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['1-mo CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['3-mo CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['6-mo CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['Cash Uses',75000,-10000,-20000,80000,50000,-15000,60000],
          ['End Cash', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

# set table
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2,columns=['Month', 'Month 1', 'Month 2', 'Month 3', 'Month 4', 'Month 5', 'Month 6', 'End'])
df_2_copy = df_2.copy()
```

Ultimately, I would like to place the output of the SUMPRODUCT at the `df_2_copy.iloc[7]` location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: In my example, the expected output would be zero since the Month-1 through Month-6 is zero, even though the price in the other data frame is 2000, 3000, 5000. 

To test if the function is working I will change the values which are zero to some other non-zero integer.

Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

Generate `df3` - values from `df_2` for particular months with *Month*
column changed to index, for rows which have coresponding rows in `df`:

```
df3 = df_2.drop(columns='End').set_index('Month')\
    .query('index in @df.Scenario')
```

For my test data, with *Month n* values changed, it was:

```
          Month 1  Month 2  Month 3  Month 4  Month 5  Month 6
Month                                                         
1-mo CDs        1        2        0        2        2        0
3-mo CDs        1        0        3        0        4        0
6-mo CDs        1        1        0        2        0        0
```

Then generate `df4` - `df` with *Scenario* changed to index,
limited to *Price* column, but still as a DataFrame:

```
df4 = df.set_index('Scenario').Price.to_frame()
```

The result is:

```
          Price
Scenario       
1-mo CDs   2000
3-mo CDs   3000
6-mo CDs   5000
```

Then calculate *sums*:

```
sums = (df3.values * df4.values).sum(axis=0)
```

The result is:

```
[10000  9000  9000 14000 16000     0]
```

And the last step is to write these numbers into the target location:

```
df_2.iloc[7, 1:7] = sums
```